# Was ist der Ursprung von "Heil" in "Heil Hitler"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Ich tue mich schwer, die "sätzliche" Bedeutung des 'Heil's im Ausruf "Heil Hitler" zu verstehen. Welchen Sinn bzw. Satzbau ergeben die zwei Substantive, die zusammengefügt werden? Ist dieser Ausruf überhaupt grammatisch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Formel ist grammatisch und bedeutet soviel wie "dem Hitler das Heil", also etwa "Hitler werde Heil zuteil" oder "Hitler bekomme das Heil".

[*Heil*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Heil) ist hier ein Nomen, neutrum (und nicht etwa der Imperativ Singular des Verbes *heilen*). Es bedeutet soviel wie "Wohlergehen, Glück", aber auch "Erlösung" in einem [eschatologischen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschatologie) Sinne, also in etwa so viel wie "Segen". Letztere Bedeutung ist heute noch im Wort *Seelenheil* enthalten. Ein weiteres Beispiel für diese Verwendung des Wortes ist der Text [*Es ist das Heil uns kommen her*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Es_ist_das_Heil_uns_kommen_her) von Martin Luther. In meinen Augen wird Hitler damit in die Nähe messianischer Vorstellungen gerückt.

*Heil* wurde auch vorher schon in Grußformeln verwendet, etwa wenn man Angler*innen [*Petri Heil*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_Heil) wünscht, also "das Heil des Petrus", oder "den Segen des Petrus".

*Hitler* steht hier im Dativ.

[HalvarF](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/44671/halvarf) hat bereits die Kaiserhymne zitiert, die wie folgt beginnt:

> Heil dir im Siegerkranz,
> Herrscher des Vaterlands!

Hier wird der Kaiser, angesprochen als der *Herrscher des Vaterlands*, direkt addressiert und ihm wird Heil im Siegerkranz gewünscht.

Ganz analog ist auch *Heil Hitler* zu verstehen. Die Konstruktion ist auch analog zu *Hail Thee* im Englischen. Näheres zu den Ursprüngen, die auch bei Wagner gesehen werden, weiß der Wikipedia-Artikel zum [Hitlergruß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitlergru%C3%9F).

Comment: Und wie kann man den Ausruf "Sieg Heil" verstehen? Man kann ja nicht sagen, dass das sowiel wie "Dem Sieg das Heil" bedeutet.

Comment: @sermonionx Das ist dann eine neue Frage :) Ich denke, dass _Sieg Heil_ soviel wie "Sieg und Heil" bedeutet. Das ist aber umstritten. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitlergru%C3%9F

Comment: Vielleicht eine Analogiebildung zu den [Turnern und Bergsteigern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heil#Jagd_und_Sport).

Comment: *Die Formel ist grammatisch und bedeutet soviel wie "dem Hitler das Heil"*: Ich würde sagen, sie bedeutet *exakt* das, da der Artikel nur fehlt, weil es ein Name ist. Vgl. *Heil **dem** Führer*.

Comment: Ist nicht "Ave Caesar" auch gleichbedeutend? Ich kann kein Latein, habe derartiges nur mal aufgeschnappt.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist wohl daran angelehnt, die Bedeutung ist ähnlich, grammatisch aber ist _Ave Caesar_ von anderer Struktur: _Ave_ ist ein Imperativ, _Heil_ ist hier gerade kein Imperativ.

Comment: Hier fehlen voreinzelsprachliche Belege, was schon daran scheitert dass eine weiterführende Wortherkunft für *Heil* unbekannt ist. Auch die Umdeutung "Das Heil dem Hitler" ist fraglich. Wo ist das Verb? Natürlich lässt sich hier ein Imperativ erschließen wenn man will, jedenfalls behelfsweise. Die Phrase ist schlicht zu unterspezifiziert um eine derartig voreingenommene, negative Antwort aus sich heraus zu begründen. Du hast in gewisser Weise sicherlich recht, in anderer Hinsicht wiederum nicht. Das sich das beides nicht gegenseitig ausschließt, erschließt sich dir offenbar nicht.

Comment: Insbesondere scheinst du darauf abzustellen, dass *heilen* "to heal" nicht gemeint sei. Richtig. Daneben steht aber noch En. *to hail*, welches hier vorzüglich passt. Ob das erst aus einer wie von dir angemuteten Nominalphrase entstanden ist, wobei die Behauptung eventuell gar nicht auf deinem Misst gewachsen ist, sei dahingestellt.

Comment: Die Partikel in "Heil dem Führer" tut dem Verständnis als Verb immerhin keinen Abbruch, weil transitive Verben schließlich auch Artikel im Parameter regieren. Einleuchtender wäre zwar die Einsicht, das vermeintliche Verb werde nie dem Plural unterworfen. Das schadet denn noch nicht, zumal wegen Auslautverhärtung kaum ein Unterschied zwischen Inflektionsendung und Partikeln auszumachen ist. In ähnlichem Sinne kommt weiters ein Verbalabstraktum mit \*-dhe suffix in betracht, vgl. etwa *schelten* bei Kölligan, *Schneidende Kritik: idg. \*skel(H)- + \*dheh₁-*, in Historische Sprachforschung, 2017

Answer (score 3):

Text der preußischen Nationalhymne bis 1871 und der Kaiserhymne danach:

> Heil dir im Siegerkranz,
> Herrscher des Vaterlands!
> Heil, Kaiser, dir!
> Fühl in des Thrones Glanz
> die hohe Wonne ganz,
> Liebling des Volks zu sein!
> Heil, Kaiser, dir!

Ich sehe es auch so, dass *Heil Hitler* so kein grammatisches Deutsch ist, aber gemeint war es sicherlich in der Tradition solcher Ansprachen des Herrschers wie in dieser Hymne, was für Zeitgenossen vermutlich keiner Erklärung bedurfte.

*Heil dir* oder *Heil, Kaiser, Dir* drückt einen Wunsch aus, ähnlich wie *Gesundheit!*. Man wünscht dem Adressaten Heil (Gesundheit, Erfolg, Wohlergehen, im christlichen Sinne Erlösung): https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heil

Comment: Ist "Heil" da ein Substantiv oder ein Verb?

Comment: @sermonion x: ich habe einen Absatz dazu angehängt,, ich hoffe, so ist es verständlich.

Comment: Ich verstehe noch nicht ganz warum du meinst, _Heil Hitler_ sei ungrammatisch? Meinst du, auch _Heil, Kaiser, dir_ ist ungrammatisch? Oder denkst du, letzteres sei grammatisch, ersteres aber nicht? Falls so, wo ist der Unterschied zwischen beiden?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: "Heil, Kaiser, Dir" ist auf jeden Fall normale deutsche Grammatik, aber das ist ja auch eine direkte Ansprache. Die übliche direkte Ansprache von Hitler war "Heil mein Führer" (ohne "dir" oder Dativ!). "Heil Hitler" habe ich wie "Sieg Heil" immer als zackige Verkürzung aufgefasst, deren genauer Sinn als Begrüßung etwas unklar bleibt (also wem eigentlich Heil gewünscht wird, dem Adressaten oder Hitler). Man kann "Hitler" grammatisch sicherlich auch als Dativ auffassen, ähnlich wie in "Ich habe Müller die Dokumente gefaxt."

Comment: Ob das so gemeint war oder eine nachträgliche Interpretation ist, wage ich nicht zu beurteilen. Traditionell besteht eine Begrüßung ja eher darin, dass ich dem Adressaten etwas Gutes wünsche ("Guten Tag", "Grüß (dich) Gott")..Aber, klar, es gab auch schon vorher sowas wie "Gelobt sei Jesus Christus" als Gruß.

Comment: @HalvarF Ich finde die Beobachtung, dass die an Hitler selbst gerichtete Ansprache _Heil, mein Führer_ war, ziemlich bedeutend und denke, das sollte nicht in den Kommentaren verschwinden, sondern in die Antwort eingebaut werden. :)